# Unable to convert multi-module python package to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I would like to convert a GUI-application from `.py` into a self-contained `.exe`. My problem is that I have actually two `.py`-files: One of them is my GUI, the other one provides three functions:

- `first.py` creates the GUI
- `second.py` offers three functions, which should be called by `first.py` via `from ... import ...`

When I do the conversion using PyInstaller and start the exe-file, I get this error:

> Import Error: cannot import name "xxxxxxx"

Any idea?

I've already tried:

1. convert both py files with pyInstaller
2. convert just `first.py` and manipulate the `.spec` file...

both without success... but I'm new in this area, and I'm pretty sure that somehow this should work

Comment: Can you add the full Traceback of the error plz, not just the message, thx.

Comment: hi Yassine, thanks for your answer.. It seams to be an error in my code, then when I run the exe file on command prompt it shows an error in the code..